# How to undo more than one commit

Tags: git

If I have the following log history:

```
d46a977 Commit 3
750bcaa Commit 2
a49d225 Commit 1
```

And I want to revert to Commit 1, losing changes made in Commit 2 and Commit 3. How should that be done?

I've been reading some tutorials, such as this https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-checkout

But from what I can figure out revert can be used to the last commit, and reset can be used to undo a few. But in the tutorials I don't see any examples of using reset where the actual commit version is specified (i.e. reset to a49d225). Therefore I'm confused how its used to reset to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git reset --hard a49d225
```

will reset your local repository to commit `a49d225` and reject all further changes. See the [manual for `git-reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

However, if you have already pushed the changes to a remote, you should not do this. In such case, I'd just check out that commit and create a new branch there.

```
git checkout a49d225
git checkout -b feature/new-branch
```

If it's not a feature branch that only you are working on but something shared by a whole team (like a `master` or `develop` branch for the whole project), the best option seems to be to explicitly revert the two commits you no longer want.

```
git revert d46a977
git revert 750bcaa
```

This will create two new commits with deltas cancelling out the original *Commit 2* and *Commit 3*. It will be visible in the history that those changes were introduced and then explicitly rolled back. Also, this way you can avoid changing history so your team will be able to safely push and pull.

That should be perfectly fine as long as these aren't merge commits. These might need some extra attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rebase, rebase your current branch to the commit 1.
(Create a branch from commit 1, then rebase your main branch to this newly created branch.)